# Как сгладить шрифт?

Tags: java, swing

На графический интерфейс вывожу текст. Шрифт создаю следующим образом:

```
private Font myFont0 = new Font("Arial Narrow",0,40);
```

Вывожу на экран:

```
g2.setFont(myFont0);
g2.drawString("рекорд:", 176,HEIGHT_PANEL-66);
```

Шрифт выглядит угловатым. Можно ли включить сглаживание и как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо включить "антиалиасинг", причем для текста в swing это сделано отдельной настройкой:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```